# Abstract classes vs Static classes in C#

Tags: c#, abstract-class, static-classes

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What's the difference between an abstract class and a static one?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2390767/whats-the-difference-between-an-abstract-class-and-a-static-one)

Hello
I Would like to know what are all the differences between abstract classes and static classes in C#
When do I use what and why?

Is it true the abstract class is a class which we cannot create  instances of it?
Thanks

Comment: This is a very broad question, more a plea for an introduction into OOP. Look for a tutorial.

Comment: Homework? Interview Question? or other?

Comment: These two things seem like weird things to compare directly.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

> I would like to know what are all the differences between abstract classes and static classes in C#.

Don't ask questions like that. I could spend hours listing hundreds of differences, none of which would be relevant to you.

> What is the most important difference between abstract classes and static classes in C#?

That's more like it.

An abstract class is usually intended to model something in a type hierarchy. For example, a truck is a kind of vehicle, and an airplane is a kind of vehicle, so you might have a base class Vehicle and derived classes Truck and Airplane. But "Vehicle" is abstract; there are no vehicles which are just vehicles without being some more specific kind of thing. You represent that concept with an abstract class.

A static class by contrast is not intended to model anything at all. It's just a convenient way of storing a bunch of code. Really it shouldn't be a class at all; VB made a better choice by calling such things "modules" rather than "classes".  Though technically they inherit from object, static classes are logically not really in a type hierarchy at all. They're just a bucket for holding static members.

Static classes are often used as containers of extension methods.

> When do I use what and why?

Use an abstract class when you want to build a model of the form "an X is a kind of Y". Like "a Car is a kind of Vehicle" or "a Square is a kind of Shape" or "a Magazine is a kind of Publication", where the "Y" is an abstract concept. Don't use it for things like "an Employee is a kind of Person" -- Person should be concrete. Person is not an abstract concept; there are people who are just people, but there are no vehicles that are not something else.

Use a static class when you want to make extension methods, or when you have a bunch of code that fits logically together but does not associate with any object.  For example, if you have a bunch of related math routines, that's a good candidate for a static class.

> Is it true the abstract class is a class which we cannot create instances of it?

**No.** That is **not** true. You can create instances of an abstract class. You do so by creating an instance of a more derived class.

```
Vehicle v = new Car();
```

Clearly v refers to an instance of Vehicle, and therefore you can create an instance of an abstract class. What you cannot do is create an instance of an abstract class that is not also an instance of a more derived concrete class.

By contrast, you cannot create an instance of a static class at all.

Here's a question you didn't ask:

> What is the implementation relationship between static classes and abstract classes?

Static classes actually do not really exist as a concept in the CLR. When you say "static" on a class, what we actually do is generate an abstract sealed class with no public constructors. Since it is abstract, you cannot create one directly. Since it is sealed, you cannot create a more derived class and instantiate that.

Comment: +1 - Eric should be a CS professor, @Eric Lippert have you ever considered?

Comment: @JonH: I have considered teaching *programming* at the community college level, and likely will do so in winter quarter of 2012 if I can make it fit into my schedule. I do not have a sufficiently deep theoretical CS knowledge to be a university professor.

Comment: I already have my MS in CS but I'd be willing to take community courses if you were teaching them.  Unfortunately I am not anywhere near your location as I'm in dreaded Michigan :(.

Comment: By community college, do you mean free for students?

Comment: @Joan: No. A post-secondary educational instutite that is primarily about teaching job skills (as opposed to doing research and granting degrees, like a university) is a "community college" here. Tuition is usually pretty reasonable. For example, at Bellevue College a course that is one hour a week for three months is about $90-$200 depending on the level of the course.

Comment: Eric, following the same logic about instantiation of abstract classes, can then interfaces be instantiated? For example, `IVehicle v = new Car();` where `Car` is clearly an instance of `IVehicle`. Using reflection API to show the case: `typeof(IVehicle).IsInstanceOfType(v)` would return true.

Comment: Don't ask questions like that. --- 15k people read that, did they need to? information like that is just wasting my concentration.

Answer (score 8):

It's true that it's not possible to create an instance of an `abstract` or `static` class but that's about where the similarities end.

- Can inherit from `abstract` cannot inherit from `static`
- Can have instance methods on `abstract` cannot have instance on `static`
- An `abstract` class can implement an interface a `static` class cannot

Fundamentally they are trying to serve two different purposes

- An `abstract` class forms a blue print / pattern which is then implemented in derived classes in different and (hopefully) transparent ways
- A `static` class is simply a container for a collection of possibly related `static` methods

Answer (score 1):

An `abstract` class is a class that must be inherited to be used — it can only be inherited.
You can create instances of classes that inherit it.

A `static` class is a class that cannot have instances at all; such a class only has `static` members.
`static` classes cannot be inherited, nor can they inherit other classes.

Answer (score -3):

True, an abstract class cannot be instantiated, but instead forms the base of other classes. The benefit is that you can put functionality into the abstract class to aid reuse.

A static class is one that is instantiated by the CLR when required. There can only be one instance of it any time. Using static classes is very useful, but care must be taken around threading and simultaneous access.

Comment: No. There are no instances of static classes.

Comment: You are wrong.  `static` classes cannot be instantiated.

Comment: What you describe in your second paragraph is a singleton, not a static class. While it's true that static classes can be used in many places where a singleton would be used, they aren't the same thing.

Comment: But, it's important to note that a class with static members _can_ be instantiated.

Comment: Does the CLR not create one single instance of a static class by invoking a static constructor? Maybe my terminology is incorrect?

Comment: @tomas: no, a static constructor, despite the name, does not "construct" anything. The Java terminology is less confusing: they call it a "static initializer".

Comment: @martinho - thanks. I think I need to refresh my memory with CLR via C# :)