# Multi Threaded Application Variable Sharing

Tags: c#, multithreading, oop

In order to check how variables (in my example "connection") are referred/shared by different threads, I wrote the following code and I found that each thread got its own connection (executing DoAnotherTask method).

I want to understand how this is handled by runtime, does each thread creates its own copy of variable and point to appropriate object, when a thread comes in CreateSharedConnection static method?

```
 public static void StartThreadTest()
    {
        System.Threading.Thread thread1 = new System.Threading.Thread(new System.Threading.ThreadStart(CreateSharedConnection));
        thread1.Name = "Thread 1";
        thread1.Start();

        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
        //Second Thread Going before First is completed with connection.
        System.Threading.Thread thread2 = new System.Threading.Thread(new System.Threading.ThreadStart(CreateSharedConnection));
        thread2.Name = "Thread 2";
        thread2.Start();

        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
        //Third Thread Going before Second is completed with connection.
        System.Threading.Thread thread3 = new System.Threading.Thread(new System.Threading.ThreadStart(CreateSharedConnection));
        thread3.Name = "Thread 3";
        thread3.Start();

        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
        //Fourth Thread Going before Third is completed with connection.
        System.Threading.Thread thread4 = new System.Threading.Thread(new System.Threading.ThreadStart(CreateSharedConnection));
        thread4.Name = "Thread 4";
        thread4.Start();

    }



    /// <summary>
    /// This is to start multiple threads.
    /// </summary>
    public static void CreateSharedConnection()
    {
        ThreadingPractice.GenericConnection connection= new ThreadingPractice.GenericConnection();

        connection.DoTaskWithSleep();

        //First Thread should invoke it again once second Thread has created a new connection after 1 Second.

        connection.DoAnotherTask();
 }
```

Generic Connection Class:

```
  public class GenericConnection
{
   public long ObjectIdentifier = 0;

   public GenericConnection()
   {
       ObjectIdentifier = System.DateTime.Now.Ticks;
       Console.WriteLine("Thread: " + System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.Name + "Generic Connection has been created at: " + DateTime.Now.ToString() + " with Unique Identifier of " + ObjectIdentifier.ToString());
   }

   /// <summary>
   /// This method is kept to make a call stuck for few seconds as if doing a IO intensive Query.
   /// </summary>
   public void DoTaskWithSleep()
   {
       System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);
       Console.WriteLine("Thread: " + System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.Name + " Sleep has been done at: "+ System.DateTime.Now.ToString() + " This object has identifier as ##" + ObjectIdentifier.ToString());           
   }


   public void DoAnotherTask()
   {
       System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
       Console.WriteLine("Thread: " + System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.Name + "Done another task at: " + System.DateTime.Now.ToString() + " This object has identifier as ##" + ObjectIdentifier.ToString());   
   }

}
```

Comment: you are instantiating `GenericConnection` in each thread's worker method, so yes. It has nothing to do with the fact that `CreateSharedConnection` is static, if this is your concern. Did you get any contradicting results when you run your code?

Comment: If you want to use the same object for each thread then consider a static class with a static property that gets referenced in the method.

Comment: This answer could help you - https://stackoverflow.com/a/3037690/2020893

Comment: uh, sorry. I did not read carefully. you *want* it to be shared. so create a singleton instance before any of the threads is created, and synchronize access to it. you did not tell us what the requirement is (do you have a scarce/unique resource, or is it about common data? read-only or writable), anyway [this may be a good starting point](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12316461/1132334)

Comment: @KarthikAMR Thanks. I was looking for how sharing/cloning of variables is done inside a static method. Variable is referencing to an object in heap and thus if variable reference changes due to another thread, it would have been great issue.