# Extension method throwing error

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, extension-methods

I'm trying to implement strongly-typed session variables in my asp.net MVC 5 project.  I found [this SO article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24148305/site-wide-variables-per-user) which I'm basing mine off of but have some errors that I'm not familiar with due to my lack of knowledge of Extensions.

Here's the `SessionExtensions` class:

```
public static class SessionExtensions
{
    public static bool TryGetValue<T>(this HttpSessionStateBase session, out T value)
      where T : class
    {
        var name = typeof(T).FullName;

        value = session[name] as T;

        var result = value != null;

        return result;
    }

    public static void SetValue<T>(this HttpSessionStateBase session, T value)
    {
        var name = typeof(T).FullName;

        session[name] = value;
    }

    public static void RemoveValue<T>(this HttpSessionStateBase session)
    {
        var name = typeof(T).FullName;

        session[name] = null;
    }

    public static bool ValueExists(this HttpSessionStateBase session, Type objectType)
    {
        var name = objectType.FullName;

        var result = session[name] != null;

        return result;
    }

    public static bool TryGetAuthenticatedValue<T>(this HttpSessionStateBase session,
        out T value)
        where T : class
    {
        value = null;

        if (HttpContext.Current.User != null
            && HttpContext.Current.User.Identity != null
            && HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            var name = typeof(T).FullName;

            value = session[name] as T;
        }

        var result = value != null;

        return result;
    }
}
```

Which can easily assign whole objects to in code-behind:

```
DBRepository repo = new DBRepository();
var user = repo.GetAppUserInformation(userId);
Session.SetValue(user);
```

All this is working great.  The issue/error I'm having is when I try to retrieve the `User` object from the session.  I see the `TryGetAuthenticatedValue` extension method but when I try to use it in my .cshtml, I get an error.

```
<span class="username">
    @{
        if(Session.TryGetAuthenticatedValue(Project1.Models.User) != null)
        {
            //Display username from Session object.
        }
    }
</span>
```

The error is at design time on `Project1.Models.User` and it states `'User' is a type, which is not valid in the given context.'`

It may be worth noting that I'm using EF 6 and the `User` class is auto-generated by EF.

Am I using the extension method wrong in the .cshtml file or is something else missing?

Comment: `Project1.Models.User` is a class. Is your method expecting it to pass a type ?

Comment: `TryGetAuthenticatedValue` uses an `out` variable. You need to do something like: `Project1.Models.User usr; if(Session.TryGetAuthenticatedValue(out usr) && usr != null) ...`

Comment: You need to pass an object of Project1.Models.User class as out parameter to Session.TryGetAuthenticatedValue method. What you are passing is class, not an object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to change the code in your view to:

```
<span class="username">
    @{
        Project1.Models.User user = null;  
        if(Session.TryGetAuthenticatedValue(out user))
        {
            //Display username from Session object.
        }
    }
</span>
```

Since the method TryGetAuthenticatedValue returns a bool you don't need to check for null, and you need to pass in a variable of the type you want to retrieve not the type itself.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Just FYI, if you're using `out user`, you don't have to assign `null` to it first.

Comment: Yeah, I know but I make it a habit of initializing values regardless.

Comment: Knew it had to be something small.  Thanks for the help!