# Windows service and static vs. non-static method for thread work code

Tags: c#, windows, service, thread-safety

I've the following Windows service code which starts a new thread to execute a long-running task. The task is stopped when I stop the Windows service.

```
public partial class WorkerService : ServiceBase
{
    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        Thread thread;
        thread = new Thread(DoWork);
        thread.IsBackground = true;
        thread.Start();
    }

    //OnStop code here

    private static void DoWork()
    {
        //Long-running task code here
    }
}
```

Does it matter if the DoWork method is static or not? Most of the sample code I find on the Web uses static. However, the code seems to be working fine without static.

```
    private void DoWork()
    {
        //Long-running task code here
    }
```

Is there anything I should be aware of when not using static for my DoWork method?

Comment: Additionally, static or non-static thread method is not matter on Windows Service application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1090650/are-static-methods-thread-safe) is a link to a similar SO question about static methods being thread safe. I always instantiate classes when working with threads and thread pools. One constructor, one use, one purpose. A thread is a special purpose mechanism and I see no reason why it should be shared or static or any gains by making your `DoWork()` a static method.

Comment: "One constructor, one use, one purpose". I like the way you think.